# Encoding and Decoding image

Tags: android, json, encoding, decoding

I want to insert image into 'MYSQL' database using json and retrive the inserted image into 'ImageView'.I done encoding as well as inserting image but not able to do the decoding and set the image to 'ImageView'.

```
    //Encoding the imageView
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.id.imageVieweditprofileuserphoto);
        BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable) imageofuser.getDrawable();
        bitmap = drawable.getBitmap();
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,90, stream); //compress to which format you want.
        byte [] byte_arr = stream.toByteArray();
        String image_str= Base64.encodeToString(byte_arr, 1);

//Image after encoding at server side(Database MySql)
        iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAGAAAABgCAIAAABt+uBvAAAAA3NCSVQICAjb4U/gAAAQPElEQVR4
        nO1c6W9cR3Kv6u735s0Mh4dFUjy0luUj9lo+13YQJIGdYAUs8ilAPuRPyJ+XAPFugBjYrLO2s+s1
        1rZsyxJ18BDP4XDueWcflQ/9ZjjiIUp8b0jCqx9IDTVHv+rfVFVXV1c9rFar8AzHg523ABcdzwg6
        Ac8IOgHPCDoBzwg6Ac8IOgHP

//Decoding the imageView
         imageofuser=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.imageVieweditprofileuserphoto);
         byte[] imagefromserver=Base64.decode(Utility.userimage, Base64.NO_WRAP);
         Bitmap bmp=BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imagefromserver, 0, imagefromserver.length);
         imageofuser.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

Comment: You can create folder in server and put images into that folder.Then get the image url and add it into table as string. then convert in to JSON and then convert it into bitmap and set as imageView Background.

Comment: I want to pick image from gallery or through camera

Comment: Then why you add database part here?

Comment: I want to pick image from gallery or through camera and then insert that image into database again retrive that image into imageview

Comment: I tried to do that earlier. but it was difficult. the i put the image url or path to db and then retrieve the image through url.